# Select prev date in column TERADATA

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a table consisting of a date column

[image]

I need to select this column additionally I need select the prev date that does not reside in db
if it exists or current data

I tried the following query

```
select hst1.QUERYID,hst1.starttime, 
ZEROIFNULL(hst2.starttime) as delta
from dbqlogtbl_dba_hst hst1
left outer join dbqlogtbl_dba_hst hst2 on 
hst1.QUERYID = hst2.QUERYID;
```

I am getting errors fetching results

[image]

Comment: The error is probably caused by `zeroifnull` which is only defined for numeric data, not timestamps.  You should use `coalesce(hst2.starttime, current_time(0))` instead. And it's not going to work because QueryID is unique. But Gordon's answer based on OLAP functions is usually quite efficient. `lag` has been implemented lately (16.10+), before you can rewrite it using `max(starttime) over (partition by queryid order by starttime rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding)`. Btw, there's already a `QryLogV.LastRespTime`...

Comment: starttime is actuallly of type Timestamp(6), getting error while executing this query .   Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3800 : HY000] Datatype Mismatch in THEN/ELSE expression.

Comment: Sorry, must be `current_timeSTAMP(0)`

Comment: Got this working with SELECT 
STARTTIME, MAX(STARTTIME) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY STARTTIME DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS ENDTIME
FROM DBQLOGTBL

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want `lag()`:

```
select hst1.QUERYID, hst1.starttime,
       lag(hst1.starttime) over (order by hst1.starttime)
from dbqlogtbl_dba_hst hst1 left join
     dbqlogtbl_dba_hst hst2
     on hst1.QUERYID = hst2.QUERYID ;
```

I am guessing that you really want this per `queryid`, so you would then need `partition by`:

```
       lag(hst1.starttime) over (partition by hst1.QUERYID order by hst1.starttime)
```